# Sharp images in iPhone app but grainy images in iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, retina-display

We're using retina images in our iPhone app (i.e., double the size).

The images render great on an iPhone 4 -- sharp and crisp. However, for the same app, the images look grainy on an iPad when run in "1x" mode (i.e., iPhone app size).

The code is exactly the same for both apps. There is no iPad version. People just download the iPhone version on iPads.

Are we supposed to use different images for the iPad?

Here is the app: http://itunes.apple.com/app/dumpling/id514239919

If you download it on an iPhone and then again on an iPad, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is when the iPhone app runs in "1x" size, meaning iPhone size -- not iPad size.

Comment: What iPad are you looking at this on? If its not the 3rd gen then it will be pulling the non retina images

Comment: @rooster117, is there a way to render retina images on the iPad 1 and 2?

Comment: The best case would be to make this a universal app and just use the appropriate image for the iPad(this wouldn't necessarily be the hi res though). It is unfortunate that the iPad 1 and 2 has that pixel density. It would be similar to viewing these images on an iPhone 3gs or older. To try forceful experiment you can check if the device is iPad and just set a background image to your @2x version: if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){ imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage@2x.png"]; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is not universal then they are rendering the iPhone version on the iPad. I'm assuming you aren't in "2X" mode so if you are on an iPad 1 or 2 your app would not be using the retina graphics so it'll look grainy. Have you tested this on an iPad 3? This should render correctly for you with the @2x images.